# How to access WCF self hosted service from remote php server

Tags: c#, php, wcf, remote-server

I created the self hosted WCF service with C# application. I want to send messages to C# application from remote php server. How can i perform this function?

```
<?xml versio="1.0"?>      
<configuration><system.serviceModel>      
  <services>       
    <service name="MyMathServiceLib.MyMathService" behaviorConfiguration="myMathServiceBehave">       
      <host>       
        <baseAddresses>       
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9001/MyMathService"/>       
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MyMathService"/>       
        </baseAddresses>       
      </host>       
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9001/MyMathService" binding="basicHttpBinding"   contract="MyMathServiceLib.IMyMathService"/>       
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MyMathService" binding="netTcpBinding"   contract="MyMathServiceLib.IMyMathService"/>       
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>       
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>       
    </service>       
  </services>       
  <behaviors>       
    <serviceBehaviors>       
      <behavior name="myMathServiceBehave">       
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>       
      </behavior>       
    </serviceBehaviors>       
  </behaviors>       
</system.serviceModel>       
</configuration>
```

This is my app.config file(ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650869/Creating-a-Self-Hosted-WCF-Service)

My aim is to send message from php server to c# application

Answer (score 0):

Follow the simple steps:

1. In your visual studio folder, you should see WCF Client.
2. Add your WCF URL to this client (`http://localhost:9001/MyMathService` in your case). Fill example data in the request and click on "XML".
3. Copy the XML and put it in a variable in PHP. Instead of your dummy values you put in the previous step, put proper PHP variables.
4. Enable PHP CURL. POST this variable to the WCF service.

Comment: Unable to get you @Jay

Comment: my php server is on online remote server. how is it possible to access using localhost

Comment: @Rakesh then replace the `localhost` with your server's ip exposing WCF. Tell me exactly what you were not able to understand?

Comment: i want send message from online php to local c# application. For that where i want to implement wcf service? how to implement wcf service? how to use wcf service from php to access c# application. i am void in this concept. please help me.